# Can I ignore the installation warning `Windows Defender SmartScreen protected your PC` when installing QGIS 3.10 LTR?

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

I have downloaded the QGIS 3.10 LTR version and when I try to install it, a Windows message appears saying that Windows Defender SmartScreen prevents my PC from installing this software. Why do I get this message and is it safe to ignore this?

I could not find anything online about this issue, other than [a tweet](https://twitter.com/atanas/status/1220709096992710657) of someone having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downloaded the installer from QGIS.org then it is safe to ignore the message.

The file has not been verified by Microsoft, so they are saying there might be something malicious in the file. There is always some risk if you are downloading software from third parties.

But for an open source project where the code is fully visible (https://github.com/qgis). That has a large user base. And an active and engaged developer core. The risk is minimal.